# Is there a way to initialise Scala objects without using "new"?

Tags: scala

For example see the following

http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functional-objects.html

The code uses

```
val oneHalf = new Rational(1, 2)
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
val oneHalf: Rational = 1/2
```

Comment: I know your example is just pseudocode but I like it!  In order to make that work, one would overload the / operator on Ints to return Rational objects instead of Ints.  That would be interesting!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using some other operator (say `\`) for your `Rational` literal, as `/` is already defined on all numeric types as a division operation.

```
scala> case class Rational(num: Int, den: Int) {
     |   override def toString = num + " \\ " + den
     | }
defined class Rational

scala> implicit def rationalLiteral(num: Int) = new {
     |   def \(den: Int) = Rational(num, den)
     | }
rationalLiteral: (num: Int)java.lang.Object{def \(den: Int): Rational}

scala> val oneHalf = 1 \ 2
oneHalf: Rational = 1 \ 2
```

Comment: How about `÷` ('\u00f7')? Otherwise \ makes it seems like  2 is over 1.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to steal MissingFaktor's answer, but change it up slightly.

```
case class Rational(num: Int, den: Int) {
  def /(d2: Int) = Rational(num, den * d2)    
}

object Rational {
  implicit def rationalWhole(num: Int) = new {
    def r = Rational(num, 1)
  }
}
```

Then you can do something like this, which I think is a little nicer than using the backslash, and more consistent since you'll want to define all the usual numeric operators on Rational anyway:

```
scala> 1.r / 2
res0: Rational = Rational(1,2)
```